# What is the best method for importing a config file from app root through a package?

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, import, es6-modules

I am building a NPM package and I want the user to be able to define a .json and a .js configuration file in its own app root. The package should read these files and its configurations to make the functionalities work.

Now I have noticed that absolute imports ("using a leading /") work, however my compiler gives an error saying it cannot find the module, which makes sense since the config file does not exist in my package.

Example in a component file in my package:

```
import config from '/config.json';
```

I also noticed that Dynamic imports work, however I prefer to not use them.

Example for dynamic import:

```
const config = await import("/config.json");
```

Is using an absolute import the best way? And if so, how would I ignore the compile error?

I also sometimes see people using "require()". Is this preferred?

Is there any better way to do this? And what about .js files? Do they work as expected? Even though they have imports themselves too?

Comment: I'm not a node guru but I think that stuff is really problematic. My possibly amateur suggestion is that you import top-level config stuff in your project from your main `.js` or `.mjs` file and then publish it via EventEmitter to any other modules that need it. It's kind-of a hack but it works for at least some situations.

Comment: from the top level it would be "./config.json".

Comment: So you mean with "./config.json" relative from the package itself? But this makes it not overwriteable for the user in its project right?

Comment: Well I'm not sure I understand, but you may be correct. Like I said, to me the way that things work with relative module references seems like a giant mess to me. The Node world seems to like very very small packages.